# How can i encode data to der in python?

Tags: python-3.x, der

I have searched all over the internet for modules that would allow me to encode/decode to DER format, but all i have seen is that you need an existing DER encoded bytes then you load it and work with it etc. What i am looking for is to create a DER encoded structure from within python.

Here are the classes im using for the certificate:

```
import asn1crypto.core as asn

class metadata(asn.Sequence):
    _fields = [
        ("version", asn.UTF8String),
        ("date_created", asn.UTF8String),
        ("signed", asn.Boolean)
        ]

class subjectKey(asn.Sequence):
    _fields = [
        ("key_type", asn.OctetString),
        ("key_data", asn.OctetString),
        ("signiture_alg", asn.OctetString),
        ("signiture", asn.OctetString)
        ]

class public_certificate(asn.Sequence):
    _fields = [
        ("metadata", metadata),
        ("subject_key", subjectKey)
        ]
```

And an example of key generation:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

ecPrv = ec.generate_private_key(ec.SECP521R1, default_backend())
ecPub = ecPrv.public_key()

ecPrvBytes = ecPrv.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
    )

ecPubBytes = ecPub.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
    )
```

What i want to do is load the `ecPubKeyBytes` and several other values such as version into a DER structure. When loading the `public_certificate` i am required to supply DER encoded data, but that is the problem. I dont have it i want to create it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What application are you targetting?

Comment: So far i have used asn1cryto and that works perfectly, but like i said i need to load it with existing DER encoded data.

Comment: I am targeting both custom certificates and server/client transmissions

Comment: And for example when i am generating a new certificate the values are all created in python such as keys and signatures, but i want to encode them into a DER structure

Comment: Please add all attempts (including the source code!) to the question. If anything does not work, provide the code snippets you are currently using

Comment: I have edited the question